# Why many equations of potential of integration omit a symbol of constant of integartion and some other equations don't omit it?

Tags: electrostatics, potential, voltage, conventions, integration

In some problem, an equation of potential which is gained from an integration does not has a symbol of constant of integration however some other problem has constant of integration. What are the difference(s) between of it?

For instance I made my original problem and the solution as below.

The conductive wire is given with the length $l$ and the uniform linear charge density $\lambda$ , and we want to calculate the potential at the point P shown as the below diagram. Then the below equation of potential is held.

$$V=\int_{0}^{l}\frac{k_{\text{e}}\cdot \lambda}{\sqrt{s^{2}+a^{2}}} ds$$

[image]

$V=\int_{0}^{l}\frac{k_{\text{e}}\cdot \lambda}{\sqrt{s^{2}+a^{2}}} ds$

$=k_{\text{e}}\cdot\lambda \int_{0}^{l}\frac{1}{\sqrt{s^{2}+a^{2}}} ds$

$=k_{\text{e}}\cdot\lambda \Bigg[\ln\left(\sqrt{s^{2}+a^{2}}+s\right)\Bigg]_0^l+\text{const}$

$=k_{\text{e}}\cdot\lambda \Bigg[\ln\left(\sqrt{s^{2}+a^{2}}+s\right)\Bigg]_0^l+\textrm{const}$

$=k_{\text{e}}\cdot\lambda\left\{ \ln\left(\sqrt{l^{2}+a^{2}}+l\right)-\ln\left(\sqrt{0^{2}+a^{2}}+0^{2}\right)\right\}+\textrm{const}$

$=k_{\text{e}}\cdot\lambda\left\{ \ln\left(\sqrt{l^{2}+a^{2}}+l\right)-\ln\left(a\right)\right\}+\textrm{const}$

$=k_{\text{e}}\cdot\lambda\ln\left(\sqrt{l^{2}+a^{2}}+l\right)-k_{\text{e}}\cdot\lambda\ln\left(a\right)+\textrm{const}$

$=k_{\text{e}}\cdot\lambda\ln\left(\sqrt{l^{2}+a^{2}}+l\right)+\textrm{const}$

Should I remove the rightmost constant?

I think that almost equations of potential of integration haven't a symbol of constant of integration and few of the equations have.

What are the differences whether an existence of symbol of constant of integration?

Comment: This question would likely be better suited to Math.SE, but I will post my answer and then it can be migrated if necessary.

Comment: Doesn't the const  appear in the evaluation of the integral at both upper and lower limits, and thus disappear in the subtraction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key point is that in practice we are only ever interested in the *difference* in potential energy between one position and another. Indeed, we can never measure *absolute* potential energy, only its difference between two points; or rate of change in a given direction etc.

When calculating this difference, the constant of integration cancels out. So we can use any value we like for the constant of integration - it will not change the final result in practical problems.

By convention we usually implicitly assume that the constant of integration is zero. In this case, this means that the potential tends to zero as $a$ goes to infinity. So it is incorrect to ignore the $k_c\lambda \ln a$ term in your final answer.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, the potential implicitly uses a constant of integration such that the potential at infinity is $0$. That is where you get the formula $V = kq/r$ due to a point charge, which you utilize in your example; in general, it would be $V = kq/r + C$.

Answer (score -1):

The integration constant should always be supplied when performing an indefinite integral. This is because the purpose of an indefinite integral is to find the function whose derivative is the integrand. That is, if we are looking to compute $\int f(x)dx$ as an indefinite integral, this is the instruction to find *any* function $g(x)$ such that $\frac{d g}{dx}=f(x)$. Given any such $g(x)$, we can always build a different function $g^\prime(x)=g(x)+C$ for some constant $C$ which will also obey $\frac{d g^\prime}{d x}=f(x)$ since the derivative of the constant is just zero.

In the special case where the integrand is already a derivative, like $\int \frac{df}{dx}dx$, it's easy to find the functions $g(x)$ because they are just $f(x)$. That is, if we take $g(x)=f(x)+C$ for any constant $C$, we will necessarily have $\frac{dg}{dx}=\frac{df}{dx}$.

This is what the $+C$ is really about when we are doing indefinite integrals. So let's think about definite integrals. One of the fundamental theorems of calculus tells us that
$$
\int_a^b\frac{df}{dx}dx=f(b)-f(a).
$$
This can be understood, though, as equivalent to the following:
$$
\int_a^b\frac{df}{dx}dx=\left[\int\frac{df}{dx}dx\right]\Bigg|_a^b=g(b)-g(b)=(f(b)+C)-(f(a)+C)=f(b)-f(a).
$$
This is essentially putting into formulas the usual strategy for computing integrals (which OP uses in the example given): first compute the indefinite integral (anti-derivative) and then take the difference of this function evaluated at the end points of the integration.

We see that because we are taking the *difference* at the end, it doesn't matter which anti-derivative $g(x)$ we choose because the constant $C$ will always cancel in the end. This is one way of seeing why definite integrals will never have a "$+C$" while indefinite integrals always will.

Now, with all of that said, there is one more thing going on in electrostatics: The potential $V$ is only ever defined up to an additive constant. This fact comes from the same place (mathematically) as the statement that potential energies are only ever defined up to an additive constant. Essentially, it's the statement that $V$ is to be the function which satisfies $\Delta V=-\int_C\vec E\cdot d\vec r$ where the line integral is taken over any path we like (in electrostatics, this integral can be shown to only depend upon the endpoints and not the path between them). Since we only have access, by definition, to differences in the potential, we can always add a constant to it. This is generally known as a gauge choice, and the common choice is to add whatever constant we need to add to make the electric potential be zero off at infinity.

For the sake of the integration in OP, however, no it is a definite integral and hence you will not get a constant from the integration.